# Javascript profiler shows each() spending a lot of time, but how to find where it is?

Tags: javascript, profiling, profiler

IE 8 and Firebug's Javascript profiler both showed that jQuery `each()` spent a lot of time, but since the `each()` is not inside a function, there is no way to tell which line it is, and there are lots of these `each()` in the global scope of the source code.  On Firebug, it can show you the file and line number, but it will take you to jQuery source code of `each()` without any call stack, so it is no use.

Is there a way to find out which `each()` it was?

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome's Javascript console lets you take a snapshot of the stack under the "Profiling" tab.

The Scripts tab allows you to step through your scripts line by line.

[image]

Comment: it says there it is a "Heap snapshot"?

Comment: ++ You shouldn't have to take many stackshots to see where the problem is. One might be enough.